# Android Menu Shown Where User Clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-menu, google-now

I wanted to achieve the same sort of functionality found in Google Now where you can tap the cards overflow icon and a menu appears next to it with options ([shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6tQm.png)).

Does anyone know how to implement this sort thing to achieve the same style etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by placing a listview under your button, and set its visibility to invisible.
Then place an onclicklistener on your button to turn your visibility to visible.